# Change specific object value after array is flattened with reduce, how to?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference, reduce

I've got an nested array of objects, which could go multiple levels deep. For other purposes I had to flatten the array of objects to 1 level (non-nested) array.
How can I update 1 specific object when I only know the id?

This is the example array of objects:

```js
let items = [
  {
    id: 2,
    test: false,
    items: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    test: false,
    items: [
      {
        id: 4,
        test: false,
        items: [
          {
            id: 10,
            test: false,
            items: []
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    test: false,
    items: []
  },
];
```

I've used this flatten method from this thread: [Deep Flatten JavaScript Object Recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803044/deep-flatten-javascript-object-recursively/36803554#36803554)

```js
function flatten(xs) {
  return xs.reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc = acc.concat(x);
    if (x.items) {
      acc = acc.concat(flatten(x.items));
      x.items = [];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

Let's say I want to update the **test** to true, **only in id 10**. What is the easiest way to do so on the original array? The reference is not linked anymore to the original array when I update the flattened array object.

Comment: recursively search orignal and update? like a dfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your objects have a hard structure you can recursively iterate their items and find your target object:

```js
const findObject = (items, id) => {
  for(const item of items){
    if(item.id === id){
      return item;
    }
    if(item.items.length){
      const found = findObject(item.items, id);
      if(found) return found;
    }
  }
  return null;
};

const found = findObject(items, 10)
found.test = true;

console.log(items);
```

```html
<script>
let items = [
  {
    id: 2,
    test: false,
    items: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    test: false,
    items: [
      {
        id: 4,
        test: false,
        items: [
          {
            id: 10,
            test: false,
            items: []
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    test: false,
    items: []
  },
];
</script>
```

A more advanced code would to have a function to walk your tree and update items.

For example here we update item with id 3 and all its descendants to have `test` as `true`:

```js
const transformTree = (items, filterCb, updateCb, parents = []) => {
  for(const item of items){
    if(filterCb(item, parents)){
      if(false === updateCb(item, parents)){
        return false;
      }
    }
    if(item.items.length){
      if(false === transformTree(item.items, filterCb, updateCb, parents.concat(item))){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
};

transformTree(items, 
  // filter id === 3 and all descendants
  (item, parents) => item.id === 3 || parents.some(parent => parent.id === 3), 
  // update test to true
  item => item.test = true
);

console.log(items);
```

```html
<script>
let items = [
  {
    id: 2,
    test: false,
    items: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    test: false,
    items: [
      {
        id: 4,
        test: false,
        items: [
          {
            id: 10,
            test: false,
            items: []
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    test: false,
    items: []
  },
];
</script>
```